# calling a derived class constructor using macro

Tags: c++, inheritance, macros

I have a code which has many derived class from a single base class. I wrote this code when there is minimum required and currently the specification changes so I need to create some 100+ derived classes.

My earlier implementation was something like

```
class Base {
public:
   Base();
   virtual ~Base();
   virtual bool isThereError() { return false;}
   virtual int configureMe() { return 0; }
   virtual int executeMe() { return 0;}  
};

class Derived_1 : public Base {
public:
    Derived_1() { 
      errorStatus = false;
      //Some initialization code for this class }
    virtual ~Derived_1() {}
    bool isThereError() { return errorStatus;} 
    int configureMe() { 
      // configuration code for this class 
      return 0;
    }
    int executeMe() {
      //execute the major functionality of this class based on the configuration
      return 0;
    }
    private:
        bool errorStatus;
};

class Derived_2 : public Base {
public:
    Derived_2() { 
      errorStatus = false;
      //Some initialization code for this class }
    virtual ~Derived_2() {}
    bool isThereError() { return errorStatus;} 
    int configureMe() { 
      // configuration code for this class 
      return 0;
    }
    int executeMe() {
      //execute the major functionality of this class based on the configuration
      return 0;
    }
    private:
        bool errorStatus;
};
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Base.h"
#include "Derived_1.h"
#include "Derived_2.h"
#include <set>

Derived_1 *dv1Ptr;
Derived_2 *dv2Ptr;

typedef std::set<Base *> ClassPtrList;

int main() {
  ClassPtrList cpList;
  dv1Ptr = new Derived_1();
  dv2Ptr = new Derived_2();

  dv1Ptr->configureMe();
  if(dv1Ptr->isThereError()){
    cpList.insert(dv1Ptr);
   }

   dv2Ptr->configureMe();
   if(dv2Ptr->isThereError()){
      cpList.insert(dv2Ptr);
   }

   while(true) {

     for(ClassPtrList::iterator iter = cpList.begin(); iter != cpList.end(); ++iter) {
      (*iter)->executeMe();
    }
     Sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

I found the above implementation would lengthen the number of line and it is also not a good practice to write such a form of code when there are more derived classes. I need to write a code using MACRO or any other type, so that each derive class get instantiated by itself and the `ClassPtrList` keeps the pointer of all the derived class.

I started with something like,

```
#define CTOR_DERIVED(drvClass) return new drvClass()
```

but I'm not sure how to avoid creating pointer to update the list. I need to create 287 such derived classes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need 287 duplicate classes?  They're duplicates because the only difference is the name -- all the member functions are the same, unless you actually plan to override 287 functions (thus defeating the purpose of this "time saving macro" you're trying to develop).

Comment: *currently the specification changes so I need to create some 100+ derived classes.* -- All you need is 1 class -- all of the difference is in `executeMe()`, which could take a number as a parameter, denoting which configuration call to invoke.

Comment: Avoid macros.  You need 287 derived classes, and they each have unique (from each other) configureMe(), and executeMe() code.  Normally, this effort would begin 1 class at a time.  For now, prioritize.  Identify a minimal set ... work them until they work as desired.  Then you work on the rest of the list, one at a time.  On one team, we divided the 287 (well, it was more like 40) instances to each team member (<20).  Everyone learned about the system, and these derived classes showed up when everyone had learned how to deal with them.  Editor copy paste did much of the work.  Compile did rest

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: not only `executeMe()` the `configureMe()` also have different code for different derived classes. The reason behind going for 287 derived classes is to access the derived class with same base class pointer

Comment: @kar I am claiming all you would need are 287 instances of the **same** class, not 287 single instances of different classes.  Also, how much different are executeMe() and configureMe() in each of your classes?  It can't be that much different, since all of the members are the same.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Most of them have mathematical calculations like add, sub, sin, cos, pow, sqrt, log, lin, tan, mul, div, delay, timeout, etc

Comment: @kar -- Then take a step back and carefully look at your design.  Those functions take one parameter (a `double` or an `int`).  Look at other programs that need to take in some sort of mathematical calculation.  How do they work?   What about a C++ program that computes values based on a mathematical expression?  Do you think they define thousands and thousands of derived classes to handle every conceivable math expression?